# Logging operations, how to implement better

Tags: c#, logging, architecture, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I need to implement logging of some calls of methods with many logging information (time etc). I can do it like this:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
OCRResult ocrResult = await ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language);
stopwatch.Stop();
// log here, with time, result etc
```

It would work, but I don't like this approach. First at all, I have many such calls in many places and I have to dublicate code. Secondly, this approach violates SRP (single responsible principle), where each call does one work. I need to do a wrapper or use Strategy pattern, in any case I should create one more class to do it. But how to implement it?

Comment: Something like PostSharp can inject this kind of method instrumentation for you . If your project is on the small side you can even use it for free.

Comment: Take a look a [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) which describes how you can design your application in such way that it becomes trivial to add cross-cutting concerns performance profiling and logging, and prevents the use of code weaving tools such as PostSharp.

Comment: @Steven agreed so long as there isn't a lot of inheritance going on which makes Decorator unwieldy fast.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Since inheritance should be the exception, not the rule, this should typically not be a problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic method that measures the time of a function and logs it:

```
public static void LogFunc<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    T result = func();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    long time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    // log here, with time, result etc
}

LogFunc(async () => await ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language));
```

An `async` version of this method:

```
public static async Task LogFuncAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    T result = await func();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    long time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    // log here, with time, result etc
}

await LogFuncAsync(() => ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language));
```

Comment: an interesting idea, but call func() does not wait execution of function. How to call it correctly?

Comment: inverting wall-known and good principles - or not if we write a system that main functionality is measuring execution time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Follow "Kfir Guy" answer's I modified his answer and got the following:

```
    public static async Task LogFuncAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        T result = await func();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        long time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        // log here, with time, result etc
    }
```

and call it:

```
await Utils.LogFuncAsync(async () => ocrResult = await ocr.GetTextAsync(dataStream, filename, language));
```

Comment: inverting wall-known and good principles - or not if we write a system that main functionality is measuring execution time ;)